# ObjectMapper with regex validation

Tags: java, json, regex, jackson, objectmapper

For my Student class, I will use ObjectMapper to deserialize a JSON into a Java object.

```
class Student {
   private String name;
   private String email;

   ...
}
```

I want to validate the format of `email`.  The obvious way would be to first deserialize the JSON, then validate `email` from the resulting Java object:

```
Pattern email_pattern = Pattern.compile("^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Z]{2,6}$", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
Matcher matcher = email_pattern.matcher(student.getEmail());
if (!matcher.find()) {
    throw new SyntaxException();
}
```

I'm wondering if there's a way to include the regex validation inside the Student class (maybe Jackson offers an annotation?).  If the validation would fail, then ObjectMapper's `readValue(json, Student.class)` throws an exception.

Comment: Consider this, instead (not original with me):
"There is no point in trying to work out if an email address is ‘valid’. A user is far more likely to enter a wrong and valid email address than they are to enter an invalid one.
Therefore, you are better off spending your time doing literally any other thing than trying to validate email addresses."

Comment: I would separate deserialization from validating. These are different concerns and should be handled in different stages, not at once.

Comment: @QuantumMechanic  email was just an example.  In actuality, I am trying to validate an ID.